# how to understand(solve) systemctl status: Active: active (running) (thawing)

Tags: nginx

description

```sh
systemctl restart nginx
```

```
nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) (thawing) since Sun 2021-09-12 00:58:03 CST; 7h ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 2049 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c /bin/kill -s TERM $(/bin/cat /var/run/nginx.pid) (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2054 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2055 (nginx)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 98805)
   Memory: 18.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2055 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
           ├─2056 nginx: worker process
           ├─2057 nginx: worker process
           ├─2058 nginx: worker process
           └─2059 nginx: worker process
```